# Commands queueing across different users

Tags: administration

I want to be able to queue commands across different users on one machine so calculation resources would be used in order and not simultaniously is there an util for that?

I found `tsp` but I think it cannot work across different users.

P.S. I'm using Ubuntu Server 16.04

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/24654/batch-processing-on-linux). Keywords "batch processing", "scheduling".

Comment: @dirkt thank you, sqs seems to be the answer